# Use exception for mod_expires

Tags: linux, apache, mod-expires

Is it possible that a file like test.js dont use mod_expires ?

```
   <IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 2 month"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access 2 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 2 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access 2 month"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access 2 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 2 week"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 12 month"
    ExpiresByType image/icon "access plus 12 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-ico "access plus 12 month"
    ExpiresByType application/ico "access plus 12 month"
   </IfModule>
```

I need `test.js` to be read by browser every time, or every hour, or at least once a day.

Comment: You mean all you .js file expire 1 or 2 week , but test.js expire 1 day?

Comment: Yes exactly ... @محمد علی پور فتحکوهی

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using the `<If>` syntax:

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ /\/test\.js/" >
   ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 hour"
</If>
```

This assumes that you're running Apache httpd 2.4, which you should be.